# Find $\sin 4x$ if $\cos x$ - $\sin x$ = -$\frac{\sqrt 2}{4\sin x}$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos x - \sin x = -\frac{\sqrt 2}{4\sin x}$ then find $\sin4x$

Comment: Had removed that question due to format problem

Comment: I attempted but I got no result, I multiplied two sides of the equation to $sinx$ but, I can't go further as the problem gets complicated more.

Comment: Formatting hint: `$cos x$` comes out as $cos x$, but `$\cos x$` comes out as $\cos x$ - the latter is the conventional notation.

Comment: @NickD thanks for tip

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit  I can find sin(2x) = 1- $\frac{\sqrt 2}{4}$ but can't calculate $cos(2x)$

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit isn't there a $1-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: Multiply the equation throught by $ 2 \sin(x) $ and add $1$ to both sides
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underbrace{2 \cos(x) \sin(x)}_{ \sin(2x)}  + \underbrace{1- 2 \sin^2(x)}_{\cos(2x) }  = 1- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Are you happy up to here ?

Comment: Thank you, Donald, well done, so now what next?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit now we should power them to two, thanks alot

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Thanks Mate !!!

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying two sides of the equation to $2 \sin x$ and add $1$ to both sides;

\begin{eqnarray*} \underbrace{2 \cos(x) \sin(x)}_{ \sin(2x)}  + \underbrace{1- 2 \sin^2(x)}_{\cos(2x) }  = 1- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}. \end{eqnarray*}

Now, we should square both sides of the equation then $\sin 4x=\color{blue}{ \frac{1}{2} - \sqrt 2}$